# MultiPostThumbnail and the_post_thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am using `built-in` Wordpress function to add (small) thumbnails to each post. In addition to the post thumbnail I am using **MultiPostThumbnail plugin** to add custom category (large) image.

Since not all posts have thumbnails or "secondary image" (as it is called by MultiPostThumbnail plugin) I would like to display thumbnails (either large or small) in this order:

1. If I a post has large (MultiPostThumbnails) thumbnail and (**small**) thumbnail display only (**large**) thumbnail.
2. If a post doesn't have a (**large**) thumbnail display the (**small**) thumbnail.

I hope now it makes more sense. It's a simple if statement but I can't get it to work. Here is a "pseudo-code".

```
<?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')
   && MultiPostThumbnails::has_post_thumbnail('post', 'secondary-image')) :
      MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail('post', 'secondary-image', NULL,  'post-secondary-image-thumbnail');
else {
   the_post_thumbnail();
}
?>
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Does the code you provided not work? Did you write this yourself or did you find it somewhere?

Comment: I added a better description of my problem. The code above is a 'pseudo code'. It doesn't work.

Comment: For me this looks like you're looking for a specific feature of that plugin. Please contact the plugin author and discuss your needs with her/him.

Answer (score 3):

In code you posted you have issue with syntax - you should stick either with braces style or colons style, [mixing them is not supported](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

```
if(class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')
    && MultiPostThumbnails::has_post_thumbnail('post', 'secondary-image')) {

    MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail('post', 'secondary-image', NULL, 'post-secondary-image-thumbnail');
} 
else {

    the_post_thumbnail();
}
```